# Can you mix .net languages within a single project?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

Can you mix .net languages within a single project?  So pre-compiled, I would like to call classes and methods of other source files.

For both web and apps?

In particular I'd be interested in F# and C#.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can mix languages in a single assembly with [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en) and [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).

[Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx) is a very good example about it.

Comment: a neat trick, but you still have to create separate projects for each language, which was what the question specifically asked - good to know about the post-build merge stuff though, thanks for the link!

Comment: Yes that's true, however in ASP .NET you can mix languages, and Visual Studio does the trick... http://tinyurl.com/4g9ohv

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can, but Visual Studio does not support it directly. What you will do is compile code to netmodules, then combine them into a single assembly. The compilers support the "/target:module" option which generates these netmodules.

You can then use the compilers to reference other netmodules when building, or use [Assembly Linker (Al.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx). There's even an msbuild task for it: [AL (Assembly Linker) Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cywecfx9.aspx).

A full overview is provided on MSDN: [How to: Build a Multifile Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226t7yxe.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

CMS mentions an interesting approach, but in reality I would suggest you keep things simple and have different assemblies (projects) for the C# and F# code. There are well documented communication points between C# and F# (such as [here](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/manual/export-interop.aspx) and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/manual/import-interop.aspx)) - I'd recommend them instead. The differences between C# and F# (especially with F# having a different runtime!) are quite large...

Comment: These two links have died :(

Answer (score 2):

you can specify the language in each assembly project (library DLL) and use several of these in the same solution, but i don't think you can mix languages within the same assembly

Comment: i stand corrected - you can merge assemblies in different languages into one assembly

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a web site project versus a compile-first project: http://www.aspnetlibrary.com/articledetails.aspx?article=Use-C-Sharp-and-VB.NET-in-the-same-project. A web site's BuildProvider resolves language elements on-the-fly.

.NET's [BuilderProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildprovider.aspx) still isn't available for non-web site projects so you're out of luck for standard app mixed Intellisense.