# How can you reference code written in another language in the App_Code folder in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Due to legacy issues I have two folders under App_Code directory. One for VB.Net and another for C#. Problem is, I have a service in the C# folder that needs to leverage a class in the VB.Net folder but they dont seem to know about each other. Any ideas are welcome :)

Thanks in advance!

Trev

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can take the code out of App_Code and add it to a class library project?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and ended up having to move the code to a class library and not use App_Code, so my answer is:

Unless someone has a solution for you, move your code that needs to be seen by both into a separate class library project.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2007/02/28/14002.aspx) is a very good example about mixing C# and VB in the same Web project...

The trick is done using the [codeSubDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dwfbb7.aspx) compilation element in your application's Web.config, to define code directories that will be compiled into separate assemblies at build or run time...

Comment: I think he is already doing that.  He is having a problem calling between those directories.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach: http://www.aspnetlibrary.com/articledetails.aspx?article=Use-C-Sharp-and-VB.NET-in-the-same-project.

See also: [Can you mix .net languages within a single project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196677/can-you-mix-net-languages-within-a-single-project).

If you're already set up as described in the article and the problem is calling one App_Code sub-directory from another, you have to refactor a bit. You mention it's a service calling the other sub-directory. Consider moving the service's code-behind to the same directory as its .asmx. That way, it can use code from anywhere in App_Code. If your service is in the wrong language for the project, you'll have to re-write it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider [translating](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) your VB code into C#? This has the added benefit of making your project more consistent and maintainable.