# Guidelines to design a C# library well usable from F#

Tags: c#, f#

I just want to point out that this is question is not the reverse of

[Best approach for designing F# libraries for use from both F# and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110174/best-approach-for-designing-f-libraries-for-use-from-both-f-and-c-sharp)

Here I'm not asking how to design a functional library written C# to be used in both worlds.

I'd like to know **good practices** on what **design choices embrace or avoid** to get a reasonable compromise for make this library **usable from F#**.

Practices like (for example):

- keep object hierarchy as simple as possible
- avoid mutating state of objects, but return new ones
- etc...

Anyone that already done it, can share it's experience?

**Side note**

It's interesting note this OSS project, [IronJS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS). Yes, it's written in F#, but the author expose two specialized host `IronJS.Hosting.FSharp` and `IronJS.Hosting.CSharp`.

Comment: I use c# library from fsharp, and never gave a deep thought at this. The few mismatch I encountered were the difference between Func and FSharpFunc, and the lack of option types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine one day you would like to rewrite your C# library in F# for better usability. Here are the paths you are likely to take:

[image]

I focus on the path "Imperative C# --> Functional C# --> Functional F# --> Idiomatic F#". *The more functional your C# library is, the more usable your library is in F#*. Functional style helps increase composability and is closer to idiomatic F# code. Along these lines, you can:

- Embrace *immutability by default* principle. If you don't know whether you need to update a field/property later, just mark it `readonly` first.
- Follow expression-based and declarative programming style. LINQ operations are good examples.
- Use immutable collections or mutable collections in an immutable way. With the [introduction of C# immutable collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx), it should be easier than ever before.

The picture above is taken from [F# for fun and profit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/)'s [Porting from C# to F# series](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/porting-to-csharp-intro/). They are very helpful; knowing how C# concepts are expressed in F# will improve usability of your library.

It's hard to avoid C#'s object-oriented features. Remember that F# type inference doesn't work very well with these features. Along the line of keeping object hierarchy simple, you should reduce number of member overloads. A big number of member overloads will easily confuse F# type checker. Moreover, it doesn't hurt to *distribute a thin F# wrapper with your C# library*. Certain things you need to do are turning some methods into module functions and creating[Active Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) to decompose object hierarchy.

Comment: +1 @pad; optimal confirmations and excellent further explanations; this answers exactly my question, that could be also expressed as: 'how to model C# code in a F# friendly manner?' articles supplied completes the picture. concluding, we can add that _immutability_ is a central topic because it 'keeps away' side effects.

Comment: The whole http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com site is an excellent resource, I only discovered it yesterday.

Comment: @pad, really excellent (I didn't know it)! I've found here also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817248/patterns-to-mix-f-and-c-sharp-in-the-same-solution) in same way connected to this topic (posted for reference).

Comment: @Benjol: Yes, it is. I'm often surprised how well-written the site is. Many SO questions can be answered by citing their articles only.

Answer (score 4):

Interop with existing .NET libraries was a major design goal of F#, so there aren't any constraints on the libraries to be consumed.

That said, because of F#'s stricter typing, there are some patterns that result in slightly clunkier code. The builder pattern is one.

```cs
var bldr = new StringBuilder();
bldr.Append("abc"); //ignoring return value
```

vs.

```ml
bldr.Append("abc") |> ignore //must be explicitly ignored
```

But this is easily worked around using an extension method or let-bound function. Bottom line: interop is one of F#'s strengths and greatest achievements.

Comment: +1 for example, @Daniel; when you talk about extension method, you mean something that returns ``void/Unit``, a way to avoid pipelining to ``ignore``?