# Mixed Language Woes in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to get mixed-language support working in Visual Studio 2008. In my app_code folder, I've created two subfolders (CS, VB), and added the following to the web.config file:

```
<compilation>
  <codeSubDirectories>
    <add directoryName="VB" />
    <add directoryName="CS" />
  </codeSubDirectories>
</compilation>
```

The main application is a VB.NET Web application (with a .vbproj file).

Any time I attempt to open a C# file from the app_code\cs folder, it treats the file as Visual Basic for compilation and syntax checking purposes. It still tries to build the classes in the CS folder as though they were Visual Basic. (The extension on these classes is, indeed, .cs.)

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could mix languages within a project in VS.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196677/can-you-mix-net-languages-within-a-single-project

Comment: @Mike: I think you have a web site and not a web application project. Is that correct?

Comment: @John, To be perfectly honest, I'm not entirely certain. Is there a way for me to tell definitively?

Comment: @Mike: do you have a .csproj or .vbproj file? If so, then you've got a Web Application Project (which is a Good Thing).

Comment: @Mike Hofer - is this an academic exercise (i.e. "Can it be done") or is this a practical question ("I want to use this approach in a project").  Either is fine, just curious which it is.

Comment: @RQDQ: Not a purely academic exercise. We're migrating away from VB.NET to C#, and wanted to be able to start converting a lot of our code to C# without having to create another assembly (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the language is defined at the project level.  You could always put your C# files into a separate C# class library project and then reference that project from your web application in Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't think he has a project. I think he has a web site.

Comment: Well, the project in question has a .VBPROJ file, and I have post-build steps defined for it. If Daniel Knoodle's link is accurate, it's a Web App, not a Web Site.

Comment: @Mike: then please update your question to indicate it's a Web Application Project (which is the "Right Thing to Do").

Comment: @John: The original question does state that.

Comment: @Mike: you said "VB.NET Web Application", but people get confused between web sites and applications. Saying that there's a .vbproj file makes it certain.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, you are using a Web Site project instead of a Web Application project.  The Web Site project is there for backwards compatibility and should not be used for new application development.

If you use a Web Application you can mix and match .cs & .vb class files in the project.  No configuration is necessary.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(VS.80).aspx#wapp_topic5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5)

Comment: much as I dislike web site "projects", they are not for backwards compatibility. Microsoft in VS2005 actually thought that was how we wanted to create web applications. We had to tell them they were wrong and, in VS2005 SP1, they corrected their misunderstanding.

Comment: @John Saunders In VS 2008 & 2010 it remains for backwards compatibility.  MS documentation for VS 2008 and above states to use Web Application projects.  I've spoken personally with several people at MS about this for past issues I've had.  Regardless, how does my answer warrant a down vote???

Comment: I did some further testing with a new VS 2008 project. @Mike, I'm not sure why it's a problem.  I'm able to add both C# & VB classes to both Web Site and Web Application projects.  In fact when I select Add new Item in a Web Site project it asks what language I want to use.  I can add classes of either language and compile / run with no problems.  I didn't do anything more than create a new project.  Try that on your machine, perhaps it's something in your project preventing it.