# Is it wrong to add razor (cshtml) and c# projects to a Visual Studio vb website?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, azure-devops

I'm creating a new **website** in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate / vb and I want to add things to it, to jazz it up.  So I'm adding new projects from the VS Team Services templates.  It seems there are many more projects in c# than vb.  I'm trying to figure out if it's okay to add a c# and razor project to a vb website, because if not, I'll start the website in c#.

Will mixing languages between projects within your website present issues in the future when it comes time to build and publish?  Or is it recommended I begin the website in c# (since there are more projects within VS) and keep the languages the same throughout the website?  Thanks!

Comment: If depends what you mean by jazz it up -  you could just develop your website in VB but add javascript/jQuery to the HTML pages which will 'jazz it up' loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is a great approach when you have a diverse skillset in your team, since some languages are better suited for specific tasks than others.

There sould be no problems with having different languages used in one solution (although you should use one langugage per project) since everything will be compiled into MSIL (some details can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/362076/Understanding-Common-Intermediate-Language-CIL)).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, Jan.  I'm just a one-man show and not an experienced programmer trying a small startup company.  I've only made a couple of websites, and both were in VS / vb, but I feel more comfortable now adding projects in C# now.  Thanks, as well, for the link!

Answer (score 3):

There is no issue in doing till you keep the projects separate. That is you should not write one controller in VB and another controller in C# in same project.

As far as i know there is no problem in keeping different projects in same solution

Comment: Thanks for responding, Deepesh.  I really wasn't sure if it would cause problems, but like you and Jan suggest, keep the languages the same within each project.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked: [Can you mix .net languages within a single project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196677/can-you-mix-net-languages-within-a-single-project)

To add a bit more, I would never suggest anyone to mix two different languages. If you start with a solution with one programming languages, continue with that programming language even when you add new projects to that solution. There is nothing worse than having to switch your way of thinking from one language to another. We had a project at my former company where one project was C# and the other two were VB.NET. Maintaining those projects was a nightmare, not to mention a lot of subtle bugs in the way VB.NET and C# evaluate things like `if` statement.

My suggestion to you is choose one language and stick to it on your project. If you want to improve your knowledge in another language, work with that language, etc.

Comment: I didn't see that question, although it was back from '08, Huske.  Thank you for helping me out.  I'm not really big or corporate; I've only made a small handful of websites.  This is for a small startup company and i was just leery of starting the website in vb (which I'm more familiar with) and adding a project in C#.  But there won't be dozens of projects -- just a few.  Thanks for your input and knowledge from your experience!