# Can we use VB.net file inside C# Console Application Project and use it successfully?

Tags: c#, vb.net, project, visual-studio-2008-sp1

If your answer is NO then please provide answer related to .Net Architecture

Comment: Vb.Net code -> Assembly Dll <-> C# Project

Comment: Creating a class library project with VB.NET code and using it in a C# console app project is never a problem.

Comment: Yes (well not really in the same project) but really? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196677/can-you-mix-net-languages-within-a-single-project

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't combine VB.NET and C# in one project.

You *can* use the end result of a project (an assembly compiled in VB.NET, C# or any other supported language) together, since it is all compiled to MSIL.

Comment: If I make 2 projects, one in VB.NET and other one in C# then can I use VB.net file in C# Project?  I mean can i make any relationship in between 2 different projects supporting different languages in Visual Studio?

Comment: It's no problem to place them in the same solution and create references to each other. Why don't you try it and ask about more specific problems you encounter along the way?

Comment: @Jens: True, but relations are always one way.