# merge vb and c# website into one

Tags: asp.net

I have two website, one in vb and the other one is in c#. I want to merge both into a single one so that they can interact among themselves. For example on my main vb page I want to have a link which open the second one.

Can you please advise if that is possible and if yes, how this can be done?

thank you

Comment: You don't need them in a single web project to write a hyper link address from one to the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you mix .net languages within a single project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196677/can-you-mix-net-languages-within-a-single-project)

Comment: they are two independent project and i want them to be under a single solution.