# .NET Core 2.2 Web-Api use F# only for controllers

Tags: f#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building a single-page app with .NET Core 2.2 in C#.

Since I want a compact server-side web-service code, I wonder if I can have
mixed f# and c# files in my project and use F# only for the controllers?

Comment: Mixing languages is probably a bad idea, not sure why you think it's useful. I don't think you can do it inside the same project, so if you were really committed to doing this, you could put your controllers inside their own F# project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you mix .net languages within a single project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196677/can-you-mix-net-languages-within-a-single-project)

Comment: Thanks for the link it surely helps! @DavidG I'm used on the JVM that I can mix languages. Not sure why that's an issue on the CLR.

Comment: I think the link by @CaringDev doesn;t take into account .NET Core though, it's a very old post. I think this is not possible in .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* mix languages on the CLR but you can't in the same *project* (as in MyPro.csproj or MyProj.fsproj files<sup>1</sup>). Splitting business functionlity in e.g. MyBusinessDomain.csproj and WebAPI in MyWebApiControllers.fsproj is perfectly fine.

---

<sup>1</sup> I guess there is a way to get this to work by conditional inclusion of source files, but I'm sure it is not supported well by tooling and thus worth the hassle.